# How to remove an object from array of objects in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this data and I want to remove a given movie based on its id/title

```
    "_id": "604184234a2f37156cec63ca",
    "name": "Jacob Tremblay",
    "description": "Jacob Tremblay is a Canadian actor. He made his film debut as Blue in the live action animated film",
    "born": "06051993",
    "bornCountry": "Usa",
    "movies": [
        {
            "movie": {
                "_id": "604184384a2f37156cec63cb",
                "title": "Luca",
                "__v": 0,
                "id": "604184384a2f37156cec63cb"
            },
            "role": "Luca"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

In documentation it says I can achieve this using the $pull, but im having trouble to figure it out how its done. My controller method

```
const removeMovieForActor = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Actor.updateOne(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      { $pull: { movies: { title: req.body.movie }}},
      { multi: true }
    )
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: 'ok' })

  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: error })
  }
}
```

Comment: To match the title, you have to provide the full path to that property. Since the title is under the movie-object, this should work: `{ $pull: { movies: { 'movie.title': req.body.movie }}}`.

Comment: Still didnt work doing like this